# automated PDF trimming, removing header/footer generated by browsers

Tags: shell, pdf, command-line-interface

It appears that browsers these days no longer allow configuring pages' header/footer - which is unfortunate when you want page numbers without all the other cruft (typically that's URL, date and title).

Assuming I have a PDF generated by Google Chrome, e.g. from an HTML document like the sample below, is it possible to remove (not just hide) that cruft with a shell script?

(Print CSS remains ill-supported, so I believe that's not an option?)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
*,
*::before,
*::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    max-width: 60ch;
    margin: 1rem auto;
    line-height: 1.5;
}
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
        eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
        minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip
        ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in
        voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur
        sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia
        deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
        eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
        minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip
        ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in
        voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur
        sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia
        deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
        eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
        minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip
        ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in
        voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur
        sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia
        deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
        eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
        minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip
        ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in
        voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur
        sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia
        deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
        eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
        minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip
        ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in
        voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur
        sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia
        deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
        eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
        minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip
        ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in
        voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur
        sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia
        deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
        eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
        minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip
        ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in
        voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur
        sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia
        deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
        eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
        minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip
        ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in
        voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur
        sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia
        deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
        eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
        minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip
        ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in
        voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur
        sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia
        deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
        eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
        minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip
        ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in
        voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur
        sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia
        deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
        eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
        minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip
        ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in
        voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur
        sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia
        deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
        eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
        minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip
        ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in
        voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur
        sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia
        deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
        eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
        minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip
        ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in
        voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur
        sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia
        deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
        eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
        minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip
        ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in
        voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur
        sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia
        deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, that's good to know - I'm afraid Edge is not an option in this particular context though.

Answer (score 1):

Browser Printing or Save as PDF is specific to each version of browser but the Majority (more than 4/5'ths) are Chromium based with either one of 2 engines (Foxit based PDFium or Adobe based Acrobat). However all Chromium's currently use a Skia print engine so there is much uniformity there. for some notes on Firefox system printing see https://stackoverflow.com/a/74336439/10802527

For User save as PDF they behave "roughly the same way". All (except Opera) will default to regional paper either A4 or Letter in portrait orientation and without headers and footers.
[image]

Headers (and footers) as supplied by a print driver are part of the print driver default functions, often there is a minimal 0.9 cm (1/3") area kept free. So in `--headless` mode they need to be set off (historically --no-margins now redundant ? but more recently `--print-to-pdf --no-pdf-header-footer`)
here are both from your ex sample

```
browser.exe --headless --print-to-pdf=%cd%\headers.pdf %cd%\headers.htm
browser.exe --headless --no-pdf-header-footer --print-to-pdf=%cd%\noheaders.pdf %cd%\headers.htm
```

[image]

OR for across all browsers
The default margins need to be modified in the HTML print instructions to set the non user defined print media layout. Where you define a PDF page `/MediaBox`. For example  `<style>@media print { @page { size: 1200px 920px; }}</style>` and the means to over-ride printer margins is by reduce the margin, so as to block auto inclusion of printer driver injection by setting them low (say less than the default of nominal 0.9 cm).

To manage odd media sizes I give [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72064779/10802527) of `<style>@media print { @page { margin: 0; size: 125px 238px ; } body { margin: 0; } }</style>`

[Or here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72002108/10802527)

```
@media print {
  @page {
    /* For different margins – use the standard CSS margin property: north, east, south, west, here it is one value */
    margin: 0;

    /* Browser default, customisable by the user if using the print dialogue. */
    size: auto;

    /* Different width and height. here using stated width="1000" height="500" can be px or pt or cm. For square, just use one value or use name like A6 landscape; note this is over-riding any above size: but we need to bump up for browser rounding*/
    size: 1020px 520px;
  }
  body { margin: 0; }
```

So applying a line in the CSS we can be certain there will be no footer nor header to interrupt the HTML flow.

```
    <style>
@media print { @page { margin: 0; size: A4 ; } body { margin: 0; } }
*,
*::before,
*::after {
```

[image]

so the "Magic" threshold is 23 points or less than 1/3"

`@media print { @page { margin: 23pt; size: A4 ; } body { margin: any; } }`
[image]

However using manual selections you can edit page styles and headers on the fly before manual printing. Or use an application with WebKitHTMLtoPDF (12.6.1 was last before abandoned) as a print method.
[image]

Comment: I appreciate your elaborate explanation - unfortunately, despite being familiar with CSS, I remain unsure whether it answers my question (quite possibly because I hadn't phrased it well): I *do* want _parts_ of the footer, namely page numbers, but I do _not_ want all the other stuff (title, date, URL). As I understand it, your suggestions are still everything or nothing?